# Android: How the get notified on connectivity change on API > 23

Tags: android, networking, connection

Until API 23 it's possible to register a Broadcast receiver at the Manifest that will be triggered on Connectivity changes.

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkStateChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

From API > 23 that doesn't work anymore but I can't find a example on how to fix this for newer APIs!? There's just said, that the programmatically implementation is via *Context.registerReceiver()* but no sentence about how to solve this in manifest.

This is a part of the online Android docu:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

The goal is to get notified on connectivity change and log the change no matter if the app is startet or not.

If there's someone out there who knows how to handle that please let me know.

**UPDATE**

Following the instructions of the first answer I created the following structure but it's still not working.
The BOOT_COMPLETED receiver is never triggered!?

***Manifest:***

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".StartUpBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <!--For HTC devices-->
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkStateChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

****StartUpBootReceiver****

```
class StartUpBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            context.startService(Intent(context, MyService::class.java))
        }
    }

}
```

***MyService***

```
class MyService : Service() {

val receiver = NetworkStateChangeReceiver()

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        registerReceiver(
                receiver,
                IntentFilter(
                        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }

}
```

***NetworkStateChecngeReceiver***

```
class NetworkStateChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "### NetworkChange received")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but no sentence about how to solve this in manifest

That is because it cannot be solved in the manifest, directly.

> The goal is to get notified on connectivity change and log the change no matter if the app is startet or not.

That is not possible.

You are welcome to:

- Register for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` in the manifest
- Have your receiver for that action start a foreground service (i.e., one with a `Notification` for user control)
- Have that foreground service use `registerReceiver()` or `ConnectivityManager` to find out about connectivity changes

For most developers, the objective is not to find out about connectivity changes, but instead to be able to take some actions only when there is a chance of a working connection. For that, `JobScheduler` and a network-required job will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even if I try the setting:

1. boot reciever calls service
2. service register Connectiviity Change receiver

it's still not working. :(

The BOOT_COMPLETE receiver is never notified on Android O, any suggestions?

Comment: @grumpyshoe: "The BOOT_COMPLETE receiver is never notified on Android O" -- yes, it is. As with all versions of Android since 3.1 or so, manifest-registered receivers do not work until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start an app component. Typically, that happens when the user starts your launcher activity. Also, make sure that you are using `startForegroundService()` on Android 8.0+, not `startService()`.

Comment: Ok, so after installation and starting the app I start a service that registers a broadcastreceiver for connectivity change.
But if the app has been killed, thers no broadcastreceiver anymore.

Could you give a small example please. I dont know what I'm missing in my concept.

Comment: @grumpyshoe: "But if the app has been killed, thers no broadcastreceiver anymore" -- is your service a foreground service (i.e., started via `setForeground()`? Your code does not show that, and background services live for ~1 minute on Android 8.0+. "I dont know what I'm missing in my concept" -- to be blunt, what you are trying to do is what Google is trying to get developers to *not* do. I strongly encourage you to revisit your app and try to eliminate the need to find out about connectivity changes in real time. As the saying goes, you are swimming against the current.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

So maybe it's quite not possible to do what i try to do.
I understand the usage of JobSchedular & Co but what I try to build is following:

The App should create a small database entry with timestamp and Wifi-Name on connecting or disconnecting from it so the user is informed about how long he has been connected to a wifi network.

Is there quite another way to solve this usecase i don't see right now?

Comment: @grumpyshoe: I do not know of a way to build that functionality that would work on Android 8.0+, except via a *foreground* service.